# How to change the font size in slideshow created using Markdown?

Tags: markdown

I want to change the font size of normal text in a dzslides presentation created using Markdown and compiled using pandoc.

```
---
title: Testing Markdown
date: October 30, 2019
---

### First slide

This is the first sentence
```

I compile the above using file(which I have named as SO.md)

```
pandoc -t dzslides -s SO.md -o output.html --slide-level 3
```

Note: I need slide-level so that I can start a new slide when using 3 hashes - ###.

My problem is : The phrase "This is the first sentence" is has a bigger font size than the phrase "First slide". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Using DZSlides as an output format causes the CSS styles for the slide presentation to be included in the generated HTML. You need to include some custom CSS to override those styles.

Create a file called `styles.html`, in the same folder as your `SO.md` file, containing content similar to:

```html
<style>
h3 {
  font-size: 75px;
}
</style>
```

Then, when you invoke `pandoc`, include `-H styles.html` as one of the options. For example:

```sh
pandoc -t dzslides -s SO.md -o output.html --slide-level 3 -H styles.html
```

For more info on `pandoc` options, see: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#options